# Codeigniter form_open() load View file twice when passing variable from Controller to View

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Controller is something along the line of

```
public function create_room($id_1, $id_2) {
        $data['id_1'] = $id_1;
        $data['id_2'] = $id_2;
        $data['query']  = $this->model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('viewFilePath', $data);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules // set the rules

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('viewFilePath');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "errorMessage");
        } else { (do the query)

}
```

My View

```
<?php echo form_open('theURL'.$id_1.'/'.$id_2.'/URLEnding');?>
```

The view is loading twice, most likely because I load the view once in both files.

Basically I want to:

- Pass $id_1 and $id_2 from the opening URL to Controller function as parameters;
- Query in Controller using $id_1 and $id_2;
- Pass the query data to View.

Is there a way to achieve this without loading the view twice?

Update: I've tried these:

- Removing load->view from create_room() (no $data passing from view to controller)

Comment: You are loading view twice by $this->load->view('viewFilePath', $data). Remove this code from form_validation->run() condition.

Comment: @RahatHameed I did try that but the view didn't run since I need to use $data to populate a table in the view and there's no $data passing from the Controller to the View. I see that I didn't mention that in the original post, will update, thank you for replying though.

Comment: "*theURL*" consist of a controller and a function (besides of the parameters), right?. so all you need to do, is to put the form validation there.

Answer (score 0):

you can create another function store and move the following code to the new function. because this code will run when you submit the form. and in form open use the store function instead of the create form

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules // set the rules

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('viewFilePath');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "errorMessage");
    } else { (etc)
```

Comment: Thank you but it's the same with other similar solutions above though.

Answer (score 0):

please change your code because view call two time so if you remove one call and other is move your second call in else part.

```
            $data['id_2'] = $id_2;
            $data['query']  = $this->model->get_all();


            $this->form_validation->set_rules // set the rules

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('viewFilePath');
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "errorMessage");
            } else { 
             $this->load->view('viewFilePath', $data);
             (etc)
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work, since I have to use $data['query'] to populate a table in the view.